# WHERE in a triple INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find all the values where empresas.id = (a number);

Here's my query:

```
SELECT empresas.nome, departamentos.nomeDepartamento, 
funcionarios.nomeFuncionario, funcionarios.email, funcionarios.idFuncionario FROM empresas 
INNER JOIN departamentos ON empresas.id = departamentos.idEmpresas 
INNER JOIN funcionarios ON departamentos.id = funcionarios.idDepartamentos 
ORDER BY empresas.nome ASC;
```

I've tried to put WHERE in the end, right after ASC :

`...ORDER BY empresas.nome ASC WHERE id.empresas = 2;`

And none of my tries have worked.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `departamentos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idEmpresas` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nomeDepartamento` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE `empresas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `funcionarios` (
  `idFuncionarios` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idDepartamentos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nomeFuncionario` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

What i wanna do is JOIN those table to return  empresas.nome, departamentos.nomeDepartamento,
funcionarios.nomeFuncionario, funcionarios.email, funcionarios.idFuncionario and then select then by empresas.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: WHERE id.empresas = 2;  surely WHERE empresas.id  = 2; You got it right in the join why do you think the where would be different I wonder? and where comes after from..joins

Comment: Actually that way doesnt works. I wonder why, because it seems correct. It just changes the companies name in all my rows to the company name i've selected.

Comment: Doesn't work doesn't tell me anything do you mean you get a syntax error or the query runs and does not produce desired result (which you haven't specified) It would help if you took the time to add sample data together with table definitions.and expected outcome as text to the question.

Comment: I've edited the answer. I've edited to explain what happens. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT empresas.nome, departamentos.nomeDepartamento, 
funcionarios.nomeFuncionario, funcionarios.email, funcionarios.idFuncionario FROM empresas 
INNER JOIN departamentos ON empresas.id = departamentos.idEmpresas 
INNER JOIN funcionarios ON departamentos.id = funcionarios.idDepartamentos 
WHERE empreas.id = 2 /* <=== The line to add */
ORDER BY empresas.nome ASC;
```

Comment: When i do that it returns : ```Unknown column 'funcionarios.idFuncionario' in 'field list'```

Comment: @Herald - must be true add table definitions to question please.

Comment: Added the tables.

Comment: @Herald It should have an `s` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, didnt understand. "s"?

Comment: it is `functionarios.idFuncionarios`, not `funcionarios.idFuncionario`. See the trailing s

Comment: Please try below

SELECT empresas.nome, departamentos.nomeDepartamento, 
funcionarios.nomeFuncionario, funcionarios.email, funcionarios.idFuncionarios FROM empresas 
INNER JOIN departamentos ON empresas.id = departamentos.idEmpresas 
INNER JOIN funcionarios ON departamentos.id = funcionarios.idDepartamentos 
WHERE empreas.id = 2 
ORDER BY empresas.nome ASC;

Comment: Ow, now i see. Than you guys for your answer.